computaton of vector fields in KAK decomposition
I want to derive the following the left-invariant vector fields.
\begin{align}
{D}_t h(t) = e^{-ad \phantom{1} k_2(t)} e^{-ad \phantom{1} a(t)} {D}_t k_1(t) + e^{-ad \phantom{1} k_2(t)}{D}_t a(t) + {D}_t k_2(t)
\end{align}

Let $G$ be a Lie group. From KAK decomposition, $G$ has the following decomposition
$G = \exp[ \mathfrak{t}] \exp[\mathfrak{a}] \exp[\mathfrak{t}]$
where $(\mathfrak{t}, \mathfrak{p}; \mathfrak{a})$ is a Cartan decomposition of the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{a}$ is a maximal abelian subgroup of $\mathfrak{p}$.
Corresponding Lie algebras, we have
$e^{h(t)} = e^{k_1(t)} e^{a(t)} e^{k_2(t)}$
where $k_1(t), k_2(t) \in \mathfrak{t}, a(t) \in \mathfrak{a}$. Now I want to apply $D_t$ on $e^{h(t)}$ defined as
\begin{align}
{D}_t X(t) := \frac{1- e^{-ad \phantom{1} X}}{ad \phantom{1} X} \dot{X}(t)
\end{align}
But have no idea of applying this formula, any guess or hints are appreciated.
The computation result is given by
\begin{align}
{D}_t h(t) = e^{-ad \phantom{1} k_2(t)} e^{-ad \phantom{1} a(t)} {D}_t k_1(t) + e^{-ad \phantom{1} k_2(t)}{D}_t a(t) + {D}_t k_2(t)
\end{align}


Using the following formula for differentiation of exponential map
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} e^{X(t)} = e^{X(t)} \frac{1-e^{-ad_X}}{ad_X} \frac{dX(t)}{dt}
\end{align}
Using this we have
\begin{align}
&e^{h(t)} D_t h(t) = e^{k_1(t)} D_t k_1(t) e^{a(t)} e^{k_2(t)} + e^{k_1(t)} e^{a(t)} D_t a(t) e^{k_2(t)} + e^{k_1(t)} e^{a(t)} e^{k_2(t)} D_t k_2  \\
&D_t h(t)= e^{-k_2(t)} e^{-a(t)} D_t k_1(t) e^{a(t)} e^{k_2(t)} + e^{-k_2(t)} D_ta(t) e^{k_2(t)} + D_t k_2(t) 
\end{align}
In the process we used $e^{-h(t)} = e^{-k_2(t)} e^{-a(t)} e^{-k_1(t)}$.  Now using the formula prove in this post Adjoint with exponential map $e^{-A(t)} \left(\frac{d}{dt} \exp[B(t)] \right) e^{A(t)} =e^{-ad_A} \frac{d \exp[B(t)]}{dt}$, we have a desired result.
